# barcode php sometimes not scanning

Tags: php, printing, barcode

I am using http://www.barcodebakery.com to print barcodes using a zebra p2824 +  printer and some users are saying that barcodes sometimes do not scan.

It doesn't happen to everyone; but one person had 2 printers and they both didn't work. They are able to print barcodes from other programs that scan; but these barcodes occasional don't scan.

Output:

http://demo.phppointofsalestaging.com/barcode.html

Barcode creation:

```
    $text = rawurldecode($this->input->get('text'));
    $barcode = rawurldecode($this->input->get('barcode'));
    $scale = $this->input->get('scale') ? $this->input->get('scale') : 1;
    $thickness = $this->input->get('thickness') ? $this->input->get('thickness') : 30;

    $font = new BCGFontFile(APPPATH.'libraries/barcode/font/Arial.ttf', 10);
    $color_black = new BCGColor(0, 0, 0);
    $color_white = new BCGColor(255, 255, 255);

    // Barcode Part
    $code = new BCGcode128();
    $code->setScale($scale);
    $code->setThickness($thickness);
    $code->setForegroundColor($color_black);
    $code->setBackgroundColor($color_white);
    $code->setFont($font);
    $code->setLabel($text);
    $code->parse($barcode);

    // Drawing Part
    $drawing = new BCGDrawing('', $color_white);
    $drawing->setBarcode($code);
    $drawing->draw();
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    $drawing->finish(BCGDrawing::IMG_FORMAT_PNG);
```

HTML/php to output barcodes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title><?php echo lang('items_generate_barcodes'); ?></title>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0;">
<table width='50%' align='center' cellpadding='20'>
<tr>
<?php 
for($k=0;$k<count($items);$k++)
{
    $item = $items[$k];
    $barcode = $item['id'];
    $text = $item['name'];

    $page_break_after = ($k == count($items) -1) ? 'auto' : 'always';
    echo "<div style='width: 2in;height: .8in;word-wrap: break-word;overflow: hidden;margin:0 auto;text-align:center;font-size: 10pt;line-height: 1em;page-break-after: $page_break_after;padding: 10px;'>".$this->config->item('company')."<br /><img src='".site_url('barcode').'?barcode='.rawurlencode($barcode).'&text='.rawurlencode($barcode)."&scale=$scale' /><br />".$text."</div>";
}
?>
</tr>


</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It can be a number of things, from settings to bad printing. I worked once with barcode generation in Zebra and Datamax O'neil labels and occasionally the problem with the faulty log was scanner config conflit. You could check if this package inserts the same delimiter and checking characters inside the barcode as configured in the scanner.

Comment: What is  log was scanner config confllit? Could you give me step by step instructions on how to do this?

Comment: The device you use to read the barcodes, it needs proper configuration. Some might need you to specify "delimiting characters" before and after your data, and some might require a verifying digit at the end of it, e.g.: your bar code data is "90237", the barcode becomes "*90237*1" (the * delimits data, while "1" is a check digit provided by the software who generates the barcode), but those are just for the scanner device to use, your data will still be logged as 90237.
Of course it's speculation, since I don't know your environment more deeply, but I think it's variables worth checking. :)

Comment: The odd part is that it is completely random. Some scan and some don't (at least the ones that are printed from my system). if they print barcodes using a different system they always scan

Comment: It also can be related to the printing model the software is passing to the printer... things like line thickness, spacing between them can scramble with your scanning.

Comment: It is being printed from the Firefox browser...Do you know of any settings that can affect this? Do you see any issues with the barcode library or the barcode being produced?

Comment: It might sound silly but did you try to scan it directly from the screen? It will depend on your type of screen (if non-reflexive) but if you can, it discards malformations in software-level and can be something of the model and the printer itself (but unlikely the last one since you said it's working on other software)

Comment: May be the part where you set the code props? Like `$scale = $this->input->get('scale') ? $this->input->get('scale') : 1;
    $thickness = $this->input->get('thickness') ? $this->input->get('thickness') : 30;` can be affecting the way the scanners read them, I don't know... Like I've said, that can be a number of things.

Comment: Thickness is always 30....Maybe I can set a preference so I user can configure it?

Comment: thickness is actually really height

Comment: Test it with less thickness, may help you